# Changing dataframe columns in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, streamlit

I cant change the 0 (see the image) in the columns or even add column name

```
 similar = pd.DataFrame()

    for question, rating in ratings:
         similar=similar.append(get_similar(question, rating), ignore_index=True)
         similar.head(10)

 similar.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(17)
```

[image]

I've tried renaming and everything but I cant change this, when I tried

```
similar=pd.DataFrame(columns=['new_text','new_text1'])
```

it just added inside the courses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `similar=pd.DataFrame(columns=['new_text','new_text1'])` will return a new dataframe with only column names but no rows.

There are two issues:

- You have not specified the dataframe whose column name you want to assign or change.
- Wrong syntax of changing or assigning column name

The correct way to assign column names:

```
df.columns = ['col1','col2']
```

To replace the names:

```
similar.rename(columns= {'col1':'new_col1','col2':'new_col2'}, inplace = True)
```